# Spring integration kafka outbound adapter error handle

Tags: spring, spring-integration, apache-kafka

How can I handle message failed to produce to kafka in spring integration?

I didn't see 'error-channel' is an option at 'int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter', wondering where should I add the error-channel information so that my ErrorHandler can get "failed to produce to kafka" type of error.
(including all type of failure, configuration, network and etc)

Also, inputToKafka is queued channel, where should I add error-channel to handle potential queue full error?

```
<int:gateway id="myGateway" 
            service-interface="someGateway" 
            default-request-channel="transformChannel" 
            error-channel="errorChannel"  
            default-reply-channel="replyChannel" 
            async-executor="MyThreadPoolTaskExecutor"/>

<int:transformer id="transformer" input-channel="transformChannel" method="transform" output-channel="inputToKafka">
    <bean class="Transformer"/>  
</int:transformer>

<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter"
                                    kafka-template="template"
                                    auto-startup="false"
                                    channel="inputToKafka"
                                    topic="foo"
                                    message-key-expression="'bar'"
                                    partition-id-expression="2">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="200" time-unit="MILLISECONDS" receive-timeout="0"
                    task-executor="kafkaExecutor"/>
</int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="kafkaExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    ....
</bean>

<bean id="template" class="org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory">
            <constructor-arg>
                <map>
                    <entry key="bootstrap.servers" value="localhost:9092" />
                    ...
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<int:service-activator input-channel='errorChannel' output-channel="replyChannel" method='process'>
    <bean class="ErrorHandler"/>
</int:service-activator>
```

Edit

```
<property name="producerListener">
    <bean id="producerListener" class="org.springframework.kafka.support.ProducerListenerAdapter"/>
</property>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any errors on the downstream flow will be sent to the `error-channel` on your gateway. However, since kafka is async by default, you won't get any errors that way. You can set `sync=true` on the outbound adapter and then an exception will be thrown if there's a problem.

Bear in mind, though, it will be much slower.

You can get async exceptions by adding a `ProducerListener` to your `KafkaTemplate`.

Comment: should I simply added the 'edit' part into my KafkaTemplate bean? (please see edit in original question.)

Comment: You need to subclass the adapter and take some action in `onError()` (or both). If you implement `onSuccessI()` you have to override `isInterestedInSuccess()` to true. The default listener (`LoggingProducerListener`) just logs errors.

Comment: I saw the onError is returns void, how to make sure the message goes to my ErrorHandler in my original question? Or any other way to implement another errorHandler that will send back information to replyChannel

Comment: Only by setting sync to true; when using async publishing the thread is already gone.

Comment: if sync=true, will ProducerListener still catch failed to produce exception of all kinds of causes?